# How to get all the rows of a table, where a column's value occurs more than once in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have table "Customer" who has 3 columns: "Col1", "Col2", "Col3" in SQL Server.

I want to get all the rows whose Col2 value occurs more than once.

Here is my query:

```
Context.Customers.Where(x => x.Col2.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

But it doesn't work. Do you know any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grouping

```
Context.Customers.GroupBy(x => x.Col2) // group by Col2 value
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1) // get groups with more than one item
                 .SelectMany(g => g) // flatten results
                 .ToList();
```